# I keep getting this error when trying to connect with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/brianhill/Projects/capstone_backend_MERN/capstone-MERN-backend/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

this is after i run node server.js

Comment: try to delete your node_modules directory and run npm install again.

Comment: I deleted node_modules and then put npm install in the terminal and it didnt work

Comment: Ive had this problem before and been able to fix it but I cant seem to now

Comment: Might be related to a version of one of your modules, possibly a version conflict.  Or your loader configuration.